# Birthday reminder

Tags: bash, shell-script

write a bash shell script to get the alerts of friend's birthday

Suppose

```
  Birthday Date       Friend's name 
  08-02-2014          : Prashant 
  08-15-2014          : prabhat 
  09 -16 -2014        : Aks
  12-30-2014          : Bks
```

for the single birthday i can do it using `crontab`

```
Step 1: create a file vi birthday.sh 

Step 2: 

echo " Birthday alerts: today is Prashant 's Birthday Wish!! him " |mail -s "b-alert" abc@domain.com
```

step  3: give execute permission

```
chmod u+x birthday.sh
```

step 4: run the script birthday.sh using cron

```
00 00 02 08 *  /home/user/birthday.sh
```

But how to do it ? to get the alert of multiple birthday  , i can create the script of each birthday , but i don't think it's best to do it . I want only one script to get the

alerts of all birthday when birthday come

Answer (score 2):

As requested, below is a working bash script. I use "=" sign field delimiter within each user 'record', and a space is the record delimiter. Note, I added fictitious emails for completeness.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
DATE=$(date '+%m-%d-%Y')
bdays='08-02-2014=Prashant=abc@example.com 08-15-2014=prabhat=123@example.com 09-16-2014=Aks=xyz@example.com 12-30-2014=Bks=example@example.com'
```

for i in $bdays
do
bday=$(echo $i | awk -F= '{print $1}')
name=$(echo $i | awk -F= '{print $2}')
email=$(echo $i | awk -F= '{print $3}')
[[ $DATE = $bday ]] && {
echo " Birthday alerts: today is $name 's Birthday Wish!! " |mail -s "b-alert" $email
}
done

To read the birthdays from a file, replace bdays='....' with:

```
bdays=$(cat Birthday)
```

The "Birthday" file contents would be in the same format, all on one line:

`08-02-2014=Prashant=abc@example.com 08-15-2014=prabhat=123@example.com 09-16-2014=Aks=xyz@example.com 12-30-2014=Bks=example@example.com`

Answer (score 2):

If this is an assignment that requires writing a shell script, look at the other answers. But if you want to get periodic alerts, for birthdays or anything else, you can use the `calendar` command, which is included in most Unix systems.

On Linux:

```
$ mkdir ~/.calendar
$ echo -e "Jul 30\tMother's Birthday" >> ~/.calendar/calendar
$ echo -e "08/02\tPrasant's Birthday" >> ~/.calendar/calendar
$ echo -e "Aug 15\tPrabhat's Birthday" >> ~/.calendar/calendar 
$ # note that you need to have a tab between the date and the event description
$ calendar
Jul 30  Mother's Birthday
```

You can put

```
0 2 * * * calendar|mail -s "b-alert" abc@domain.com
```

in your crontab, to run every morning at 2AM (or just `calendar`, since `cron` will mail the output of commands to you). On some systems, `calendar` runs for everyone by default early each morning.

You can put `calendar` in your `~/.bash_profile` to run every time you login.

Comment: You'd have to 'parse' the output of calendar to know who you are emailing to, and you'd need to write a wrapper to have all notifications run in one cron entry.  Your calendar solution is more advanced than a 'Birthday' file, but maintenance of the entries is also more complicated. If you can put names and emails in your calendar entry, you'd be on the right track. I'd like to see the whole script to see if it is really and improvement, though.

Comment: Oh. If the OP wants the mail destination to potentially be different for each friend's birthday, there'd likely need to be multiple calendar files. Is that what the OP wanted?

Comment: I automated the birthday wishes for the OP ;-)  But, I like the idea of the calendar program acting as the 'database'.  If we can give the poster a complete syntax to 1) add/delete users with necessary data (such as name and email of person's birthday), and 2) the wrapper script that can parse the output and send the email, then your solution, though more 'complicated', might be considered more 'elegant', as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer in dodgy pseudocode.  You can implement in any language you like.

With a file of consistent formatted dates (called 'birthdays').

```
today=GET_TODAYS_DATE()
While not end of file birthdays
do
  read from file DATE NAME
  if today=DATE then
       mail address with "Today is NAME's birthday"
  endif
endwhile
```

Run it every day in cron at 1 minute past midnight.

Comment: How it 'll read the date only from file "Birthday"

Comment: Actually, poster requested a bash script.

Comment: Yes he did.  Feel free to vote my answer down.